Unable to host nextjs app(SSG) with base Path in Azure static web app
I have a nextjs app with basePath set.
//next.config.mjs
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
const nextConfig = {
  basePath: '/app1',
  output: 'export',
  webpack(config, { isServer }) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    });
    config.plugins.push(
      new NextFederationPlugin({
        name: 'someremotemfe',
        filename: `static/${isServer ? 'ssr' : 'chunks'}/remoteEntry.js`,
        dts: false,
        exposes: {
          './Component1': './components/component/Component1',
        },
        extraOptions: {
          exposePages: false,
        },
      }),
    );
    return config;
  },
};

I'm trying to deploy this web app that is available under localhost:3001/app1 to SWA. Currently the remote url for MFE or static assets are available at https://localhost:3001/app1/_next....
Here is my azure static web app deployment yaml file.

            - task: Bash@3
              displayName: Build using turbo
              inputs:
                targetType: 'inline'
                script: |
                  pnpm run build
              env:
                NEXT_PUBLIC_MFE_HOST_URL: ${{ parameters.MfeHostUrl }}
            - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
              displayName: 'Deploy to SWA'
              inputs:
                app_location: 'apps/ui/out'
                api_location: 'apps/api'
                output_location: ''
                skip_app_build: true
                skip_api_build: true
                verbose: true
                azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ parameters.DeploymentToken }}
              env:
                IS_STATIC_EXPORT: true


staticwebapp.json
{
  "globalHeaders": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  },
  "platform": {
    "apiRuntime": "node:18"
  }
}


How can I make sure to host everything under https://...staticapps.net/app1/ ?
update:Added sample repo, I can't share original code, but the idea is same. https://github.com/kkankala/next-basepath-hosting

Can you provide the Github repo?

Can you share your staticwebapp.config.json (if created)? It controls how Azure handles routes and rewrites.

@SirraSneha, I dont have any rewrites etc in staticwebapp.config.json file.

Please share your github repo if possible?

Add this in your  staticwebapp.config.json
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/app1/*",
      "rewrite": "/app1/index.html"
    }
  ]
}


Sorry I dont have any public repo set up yet. I'll try to do that sometime later today.

Can you please add the above provided code in your staticwebapp.config.json file and check whether it's working or not

no luck. still 404.

It would be helpful if you could provide your GitHub repo to resolve the issue.

here it is - https://github.com/kkankala/next-basepath-hosting

I tried your sample project of the Next.js application and successfully deployed it to the Azure Static Web App via GitHub Actions.
I updated the routes in the staticwebapp.config.json file to set the base path for the Azure Static Web App, as shown below
"routes": [
    {
      "route": "/blog*",
      "rewrite": "/index.html"
    }
  ]

blog/staticwebapp.config.json :
{
  "globalHeaders": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  },
  "platform": {
    "apiRuntime": "node:18"
  }  ,
"routes": [
    {
      "route": "/blog*",
      "rewrite": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
}

next.config.mjs :
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
  output: 'export',
  basePath: '/blog',
};
export default nextConfig;

Workflow file :
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main  
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main  

env:
  ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG: true 

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false  

      - name: List Directory Contents
        run: ls -R 

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install
        working-directory: ./blog 
        
      - name: Build the Application
        run: npm run build --if-present
        working-directory: ./blog  

      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1  
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_LEMON_OCEAN_09FDCA10F }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          action: "upload"  
          app_location: "./blog" 
          output_location: "out" 

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job

    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1  
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_LEMON_OCEAN_09FDCA10F }}
          action: "close"

Azure Static Web App Output :
I successfully obtained the base path of the blog in the Azure Static Web App output, as shown below.


Any idea why css is not loading? I also think this is only loading the static index.html page, but not any js n css etc.. It could be related to redirect everything(so 200 for request) but actual content is not delivered.
https://lemon-ocean-09fdca10f.5.azurestaticapps.net/blog/_next/static/css/a2fe316cdd23b4ed.css also returned  index.html but not actual css content like https://lemon-ocean-09fdca10f.5.azurestaticapps.net/_next/static/css/a2fe316cdd23b4ed.css

@Kalyan The issue seems to be with the route configuration. The /blog* route rewrites all requests, including static assets like CSS, to index.html. To fix this, add a route to correctly serve static files. {
"route": "/_next/static/*",
"rewrite": "/_next/static/"
}

no luck with it. does SWA support wild card routes?
